# Pagina de Captcha no tiene imagen

Tags: bug, estado-completado, diseño

La [pagina de Captcha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/captcha) no tiene una imagen; la enlace https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/captcha.png no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otros sitios de la red se muestran una imagen:

- https://stackoverflow.com/captcha
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/captcha
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/captcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report; this is fixed now. The actual filename is `captcha.jpg`. ‍♂️